# UDK - deferred rendering?

Tags: udk

I plan to use UDK on PC to create commercial game. Can I use deferred rendering in UDK? Or it's only available with expensive UE3 license?

Answer (score 2):

With UDK, you have access to the whole UE3 kit, you will have to pay only when you start earning money. This means you have access to the deferred rendering.

> UDK provides access to the full UE3 feature set

Source: http://www.unrealengine.com/files/downloads/Why_Independent_Developers_Turn_To_UDK.pdf

It could be expensive, if you are making millions. But still their royalties are quite fair